# Error while updating table com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException

Tags: jsp, jdbc

```
if(hidPass.equals(pass)){
            String encodedPass = Base64.encode(newPass.getBytes(), Base64.BASE64DEFAULTLENGTH);
            try{
                String connectionURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/books";// books is the database  
                Connection connection=null;  
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");  
                  connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL, "root", "bonnysingh");  
                  Statement st = connection.createStatement();

                   st.executeUpdate("UPDATE signup SET password="+encodedPass+"WHERE Username="+CurrentUser);
                   System.out.println("Update Complete");
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println(e);
                response.sendRedirect("view.jsp");
            }
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Update InComplete");
        }
```

I am getting this error

com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE Username=Damanpreet' at line 1

can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should use a `PreparedStatement`, otherwise your method is prone to [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks. Second, when you send `String`s to your query, they must be enclosed by `'` or  `"` depending on the database engine. Third, you **must always** close the resources after its use to not generate memory leaks. In this case, you should close the `PreparedStatement` and the `Connection`.

After adapting your code based on these advices, it should be like this:

```
Connection connection=null;
PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
try {
    String connectionURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/books";// books is the database  
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");  
    connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL, "root", "bonnysingh");  
    String updateSql = "UPDATE signup SET password = ? WHERE Username = ?";
    pstmt = connection.prepateStatement(updateSql);
    pstmt.setString(1, encodedPass);
    pstmt.setString(2, CurrentUser);
    pstmt.executeUpdate();
    System.out.println("Update Complete");
} catch(Exception e) {
    //System.out.println(e);
    //handle the exception!
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    if (pstmt != null) {
        try {
            pstmt.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStacktrace();
        }
    }
    if (connection != null) {
        try {
            connection.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStacktrace();
        }
    }
}
response.sendRedirect("view.jsp");
```

Comment: @DamanpreetSingh You're welcome. Also, remember to always handle your exceptions. Do not just do a `System.out.println(e)` since you won't have enough info to detect the exceptions when the product is in production stage.

Answer (score 0):

Username is a String. Mysql expects or a quoted string `where Username="bob"` either a like operator `where Username like "bob"`

Answer (score -1):

Looks like maybe you need a space before the WHERE in your statement...

```
st.executeUpdate("UPDATE signup SET password="+encodedPass+" WHERE Username="+CurrentUser);
```

Also, you need single quotes around the variable.

Comment: Did you do it with the single quotes like this: st.executeUpdate("UPDATE signup SET password= '"+encodedPass+"' WHERE Username="+CurrentUser);

Comment: Now the error is...com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'Damanpreet' in 'where clause'

Comment: So... this is a problem of quotes !  Try this : `ss+"' WHERE Username=\""+CurrentUser+"\"");`

Comment: You will also need to put single quotes on the CurrentUser variable, along with an end quote, I believe.

Comment: @DamanpreetSingh This can *solve* the problem but don't solve major problems on the code: SQL Injection and closing the resources.

Comment: @Luiggi very true. I didn't get into the other stuff.